# Hide <li Class> through Body (No Header Access or CSS)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I do not have access to the header and I cannot apply any custom CSS, I am curious if there is a way to append "display none" or a value "hidden (or anything!) to an existing LI class so it does not appear when I am on a specific page?

Here is Header HTML

```
<header>
    <nav class="mean-nav">
        <ul id="member-menu-1">
            <li class="class-1">...</li>
            <li class="class-2">...</li>
            <li class="class-3">...</li>
            <li class="class-4">...</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Here is What I am looking for at the page level:

```
<header>
    <nav class="mean-nav">
        <ul id="menu-member-menu-e">
            <li class="class-1">...</li>
            <li class="class-2" style="display: none;">...</li>
            <li class="class-3">...</li>
            <li class="class-4">...</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<body>
    <ANY FUNCTION THAT CAN APPEND <style="Display: none;"> To <li class="class-2">
</body>
```

Comment: What about `$('li.class-2').hide();`?

Comment: _it does not appear when I am on a specific page_ : Is it the `<ul>`ID which determinate the _specific_ page ? So it should be `$('#menu-member-menu-e .class-2').hide();`

Comment: You can just use an inline `<style></style>` tag - just about every browser will read and apply the css rules within

Comment: Well... Should you be using your `<body>` tag like that? From my understanding the `<header>` is part of the [semantic elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp), but should be place within the `<body>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to hide the element using jQuery :

```
$('li.class-2').hide();
```

**NOTE :** the `hide()` function will add `style="display: none;"` to the element automatically.

Hope this helps.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav class="mean-nav">
    <ul id="menu-member-menu-e">
      <li class="class-1">...</li>
      <li class="class-2">...</li>
      <li class="class-3">...</li>
      <li class="class-4">...</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<body>
  <script>
    $('li.class-2').hide();
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It works! Thank You (Note - I had tried similar code prior BUT it was the addition of the script src in the header that made it work)